# Using if condition on a list object value and a string excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to List Objects in VBA. I have a ListObjects table and based on the data in a cell in that table, I want to update another sheet in the workbook. I have the code written as below.

```
Set tb1 = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1")

For i = 2 To Count
    If tb1.Range(i, 6).Value = "Yes" Then
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i,1).Value = tb1.Range(i,1).Value
    Endif
Next i
```

But I get the type mismatch error in the If condition. Can you suggest how I can proceed with this?

Thanks in advance!

Regards,
Hari

Comment: How are you defining tb1?  Listobject? TableObject?

Comment: What sort of data do you have in the 6th column of your table?  Any error codes (`#N/A` etc)?

Comment: Do you have `Count = tb1.ListRows.Count` before the `For` block after `Set tb1`?

Answer (score 0):

Have  you specified Count in  your  For statement?

remove  value  from  your if condition  like :

```
If tb1.Range(i, 6) = "Yes" Then
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i,1) = tb1.Range(i,1)
Endif
```